# How to dynamically update the attributes of the footer class of a modal dialog in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The class name defined by antd is `.ant-modal-footer`, in my css I have something like below. What I would like is to be able to change the `position` attribute dynamically via code. I am using React.

There is a `bodyStyle` property, which I can dynamically update, but I don't see one for the footer.

Any ideas?

```
.ant-modal-footer {
    padding: 14px 30px 30px;
    background: #f0f4f9;

    @media (max-width: 568px) {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can always use modal's classname to select and change footer style.

something like:

```
.my-modal-class .ant-modal-footer{
  background: red;
}
```

and then

```
<Modal className="my-modal-class" />
```

it should select and modify the footer.

also there is `wrapClassName` prop

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/z3jlokmjyl

NOTE: in the example I'm showing how to change the whole footer node, if it's just postion what you want to change, footer is a ReactNode, you should be able to manipulate the position

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't answer the question I think. How then do you dynamically update the background to be `green` for example? In the code, I can dynamically apply styles to a div, how do I apply it to the footer?

Comment: just like how you would handle dynamic css with react, update the answer to showcase